# Why won't ADB Shell let me run backup-data-partition.sh in /cache/imaging?

Tags: android, shell, file-not-found

I know it's there, because `ls` shows it to me, but every time I try to run it, it says `No such file or directory`, or simply `not found`.

Here's the contents of my terminal:

```
C:\Users\benleggiero>adb shell
root@android:/ # cd /cache/imaging
cd /cache/imaging
root@android:/cache/imaging # ls
ls
backup-data-partition.sh
data-partition-imager.sh
flag-imaging-mode-boot.sh
flags
restore-data-partition.sh
root@android:/cache/imaging # ./backup-data-partition.sh
./backup-data-partition.sh
/system/bin/sh: ./backup-data-partition.sh: not found
127|root@android:/cache/imaging # . ./backup-data-partition.sh
. ./backup-data-partition.sh
/system/bin/sh: .: ./backup-data-partition.sh: No such file or directory
1|root@android:/cache/imaging # sh ./backup-data-partition.sh
sh ./backup-data-partition.sh
sh: ./backup-data-partition.sh: No such file or directory
127|root@android:/cache/imaging # sh backup-data-partition.sh
sh backup-data-partition.sh
sh: backup-data-partition.sh: No such file or directory
127|root@android:/cache/imaging #
127|root@android:/cache/imaging # chmod 777 backup-data-partition.sh
chmod 777 backup-data-partition.sh
Unable to chmod backup-data-partition.sh: No such file or directory
10|root@android:/cache/imaging #
```

Comment: Are you typing or tab-completing the file name? If you pipe the `ls` output into `xxd` or `hexdump` or `od` or something what do you get for the name? Does it work if you use the full path to the file?

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm typing it, because the tab key inserts a tab character. I think this is what you want? pastebin.com/drbKpQik `od |ls` gives the same result.

Comment: @EtanReisner  Using `/cache/imaging/backup-data-partition.sh` also results in a `not found`.

Comment: Pipe the other way around: `ls | hexdump`/etc. I want to see if perhaps the characters aren't what you think they are there.

Comment: @EtanReisner ah, sorry. Here: http://pastebin.com/BGpbvbNy

Comment: I'm not positive but it looks like all but the `flags` file there may have a `\r` character at the end of their names. Does your `ls` there have a `-Q` argument? What do you get if you run `ls -Q`? Does `$'./backup-data-partition.sh\r'` work?

Comment: @EtanReisner I'll try that and get back asap. Also, a colleague of mine was having the same issue and said it might be due to two directories with the exact same name, created by a buggy `.sh` script. I'll look into that as well.

Comment: It shouldn't be possible to create two directories with the same exact name. The filesystem shouldn't allow that.

Comment: @EtanReisner correct, it should not be possible. Also, this error should not happen.